# connected subspaces need to lie in one separated component

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Let ($X,\tau)$ be a top space. Suppose $Y \subset X$ is a connected subspace given the subspace topology. If $A \cup B$ is a separation of the space $X$ then $Y$ lies entirely in $A$ or $B$.

I just want a verification:

Suppose other wise then $\exists a \in Y$ such that $a \in A$ and $\exists b \in Y$ such that $b \in B$.

I claim that

$$Y \cap X = Y \cap (A \cup B) = (Y \cap A) \cup (Y \cap B)$$

Forms a separation of $Y$.

As $Y$ inherits the subspace topology, the topology on $Y$ can be given by

$$\tau_Y = \{Y \cap U \mid U \in \tau\}$$

Then since $A,B \in \tau$ we have that $Y \cap A,Y \cap B \in \tau_Y$, i.e., are both open in $Y$.

Clearly both are nonempty by existence of $a,b$ up top.

Lastly for disjointness, suppose $\exists \alpha \in (Y \cap A) \cap (Y \cap B)$, then $\alpha \in A \cap B$ contradicting $A,B$ being disjoint (since they were assumed to form a separation of our parent space) and thus

$$(Y \cap A) \cap (Y \cap B) = \emptyset$$

hence

$$Y = (Y \cap A) \cup (Y \cap B)$$

forms a separation of $Y$ contradicting it being a connected subspace $\blacksquare$

Comment: Looks perfect to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This community wiki solution is intended to clear the question from the unanswered queue.

Yes, your proof is correct.